# NA values in column is not NaN Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I got a CSV File. I got a column Product. One of the products in it, called 'NA'. I want to get all 'NA' products. But if you read the file in python, the NA products get to be NaN value.

CSV looks like this:

| Contact | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NA |
| 2 | ZE |
| 3 | HE |
| 3 |  |

In python i get this

| Contact | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NaN |
| 2 | ZE |
| 3 | HE |
| 4 | NaN |

How can i change this.

Comment: please add a minimal reproducible output, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

The `read_csv` method in `pandas` has the parameters `na_values` and `keep_default_na`, detailed in [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), which determine which text values are converted to `NaN`. At its most basic level, you could do:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(your_file, keep_default_na=False)
```

And your 'NA' strings would no longer be converted to `NaN`. However this might have unintended consequences for other areas of your data, which would require refinement through `na_values`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) you can do:

```
df = pd.read_csv("filename CSV", keep_default_na=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) doc

> na_values: scalar, str, list-like, or dict, optional
> Additional strings to recognize as NA/NaN. If dict passed, specific per-column NA values. 
>  **By default the following values are interpreted as NaN: ‘’, ‘#N/A’, ‘#N/A N/A’, ‘#NA’, ‘-1.#IND’, ‘-1.#QNAN’, ‘-NaN’, ‘-nan’, ‘1.#IND’, ‘1.#QNAN’, ‘’, ‘N/A’, ‘NA’, ‘NULL’, ‘NaN’, ‘n/a’, ‘nan’, ‘null’.**

So, `NA` will automatically be read as `NaN`, but there is additional parameter called `keep_default_na`, you can pass `False` to this parameter if you want to change that default behavior:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(path, keep_default_na=False)

   Contact Product
0        1      NA
1        2      ZE
2        3      HE
3        3
```

But you may need to specify the values which you want pandas to represent as `NaN`, passing a list of such values, or a dictionary where key is the column and value is the values to represent as `NaN`.

```py
df = pd.read_csv(path, keep_default_na=False, na_values=[''])

   Contact Product
0        1      NA
1        2      ZE
2        3      HE
3        3     NaN
```